# Can't get media metadata compat string

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm creating a kotlin app. I have an issue with mediaMetadataCompat. Maybe I have to put data to extras? I put data like this

```
 audios = allAudios!!.map { audio ->
                    MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
                        .putString(METADATA_KEY_WRITER, audio.writer._id)
                        .putString(METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, audio.writer.name)
                        .putString(METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_SUBTITLE, audio.writer.name)
                        .putString(METADATA_KEY_MEDIA_ID, audio._id)
                        .putString(METADATA_KEY_TITLE, audio.title)
                        .putString(METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_TITLE, audio.title)
                        .putString(METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_ICON_URI, audio.writer.image)
                        .putString(METADATA_KEY_DATE, audio.createdAt)
                        .putString(METADATA_KEY_MEDIA_URI, audio.filePath)
                        .putString(METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_DESCRIPTION, audio.description)
                        .build()
                }
```

Get it like this

```
fun MediaMetadataCompat.toAudio(): Audio? {
    return let {
        Audio(
            _id = it.description.mediaId ?: "",
            title = it.description.title.toString(),
            filePath = it.description.mediaUri.toString(),
            description = it.description.description.toString(),
            writer = User(
                _id = it.description.extras?.getString("writerId").toString(),
                name = it.description.subtitle.toString(),
                image = it.description.iconUri.toString()
            ),
            tags = listOf("Shit"),
            listened = 1,
            language = "en",
            isForKids = false,
            duration = 70,
            createdAt = "2020:01:01"
        )
    }
}
```

It only gives my title, icon_uri, media_uri and media_id

Answer (score 1):

Sharing a small part of my code:

Below is building object of MediaMetaDataCompat. I am adding couple of data there and have used in different parts of app.

```
 var media = MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
        .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_MEDIA_ID, data.id.toString())
        .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, data.artist_name)
        .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, data.title)
        .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_MEDIA_URI, data.audio_path)
        .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DATE, data.track_year)
        .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_ICON_URI, data.image_path)
        .putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, data.duration.toLong())
        .build()
```

mediaItem is object of MediaMetadataCompat and that is how I am getting values of the fields which was added to object.

```
    mediaItem is object of MediaMetadataCompat

    var artist =  mediaItem.bundle.getString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST)!!
    var title =  mediaItem.bundle.getString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE)!!
    var duration = mediaItem.bundle.getLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION)!!
    var icon = mediaItem.bundle.getString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_ICON_URI)!!
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm new in Kotlin, so it's a bit difficult for me.

Comment: Welcome and Good luck